# Запятая между подлежащим и сказуемым?

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

http://rus.1september.ru/articlef.php?ID=200501306:

В позиции подлежащего может быть прямая речь: 17) «Приезжай, помоги, без тебя как без рук», – было написано в письме. (Ю.Нагибин) (было написано кто? что? «Приезжай, помоги»).

Тогда получается, что между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит запятая. Разве это возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Прямая речь - одно предложение, слова автора - другое. Кстати, оба односоставные и подлежащего нет ни в одном.
В статье Чупашевой (на неё указывает ссылка в вопросе) сказано, что прямая речь ***может находиться в позиции*** подлежащего, а не то, что она ***является*** подлежащим.

Answer (score 0):

Предложения с прямой речью - сложные. Поэтому главные члены одного не имеют отношения к главным членам другого.